# Creating new column in workflow task list in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-server

I have created a Document Library as '`Sample1`' and it has 2 fields as Form Title, Date. I am getting user data for Form Title and Date and I have created a workflow for '`Sample1`' in SharePoint Designer 2013.

The associated task list of '`Sample1`' is '`Tasks`' and it has field as Title, Status etc. Now I created a new column as 'Testing_Field' in '`Tasks`' list. How to map the '`Sample1`' library 'Form Title' to '`Testing_Field`' in 'Tasks'.

Comment: You mean a lookup field?

Answer (score 1):

Within the workflow you can update the 'Testing_Field' in 'Tasks' based on 'Form Title' value (current field).